# Why do these two ways of using np.pad in python with matrixes result in seemingly different results and is there a way to fix that?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix that is [100, 94] full of numbers.
What I want to do:
`np.pad(matrix, [(0,0),(0,6)], 'constant', constant_values=(1))`
This code results in a matrix that is [100, 0], when I expected a [100, 100] matrix.

If I instead do
`np.pad(matrix, [(0,6),(0,0)], 'constant', constant_values=(1))`
I end up with a [106, 94] matrix as expected.

Is this just a bug in np.pad? I want to make it a 100 x 100 matrix where the 6 padded at the end numbers are all 1.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my issue. I was looking at the wrong line of code for the error:
`np.pad(matrix, [(0,6),(0,0)], 'constant', constant_values=(1))` was actually working as expected!